# Try to import csv file to Python notebook Jupyter but the file does not exist

Tags: python, csv

i am trying to load a csv file into Pandas. I am getting a weird error that I have never encountered before that the file does not exist even though it does. i have tried different way to fix it like change slashes to backslashes() and add r before 'c:' like(r'c:/) but still does not work

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib  inline

df =pd.read_csv(‘C:/Users/caol3/Downloads/Data Sampler.csv’)

IOErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3740a47c4f96> in <module>()
----> 1 df =pd.read_csv('C:/Users/caol3/Downloads/Data Sampler.csv')

/opt/conda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in    parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
560                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
561 
--> 562         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
563 
564     parser_f.__name__ = name

/opt/conda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
313 
314     # Create the parser.
--> 315     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
316 
317     if (nrows is not None) and (chunksize is not None):

/opt/conda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
643             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
644 
--> 645         self._make_engine(self.engine)
646 
647     def close(self):

/opt/conda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in _make_engine(self, engine)
797     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
798         if engine == 'c':
--> 799             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
800         else:
801             if engine == 'python':

/opt/conda/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.pyc in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1211         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1212 
    -> 1213         self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1214 
   1215         # XXX

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:3427)()

pandas/parser.pyx in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source     (pandas/parser.c:6861)()

IOError: File C:/Users/caol3/Downloads/Data Sampler.csv does not exist
```

Comment: this is `‘` not a single quotion use this `'` so the code should be `df =pd.read_csv('C:/Users/caol3/Downloads/Data Sampler.csv')`

Comment: i tried it already, still does not work

Comment: working for me check it again or check for file existance `>>> df =pd.read_csv('C:\Users\hisha\Desktop\Data Sampler.csv')
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [gfhfgh, ftyhfth, gjg]
Index: []`

Comment: A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration

Comment: i checked it again and the file is existing but there is another problem here, does it related to my first problem?

Comment: i think it is related to jupyter

Comment: try another browser

Comment: i fixed my issue, i open the notebook with this link  https://try.jupyter.org/ , and then there is connection problem, but i try to use  Anaconda prompt and type in ipython notebook, it  opens a different window and it works to my second problem

Answer (score 0):

Please disconnect jupyter notebook and reconnect it again. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that Jupyter Notebooks sometimes truncates the filename if you use pwd to find your path. Therefore if you copy and paste the output (to pwd), and use it in naming your Dataframe, you may get a "File not found" error.

The best way to get the filename is to click in the top bar with your notebook name (if you've named the notebook with the filename itself).

You'll still need to add '.csv' in the code for establishing your Dataframe name.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the game here. Possible you haven't actually saved your file as a CSV file. It could still be in `.xlsx`format, in which your file will have the format `file.csv.xlsx`.Follow the steps below (if you haven't done so):

```
In your Excel spreadsheet, click File.
Click Save As.
Click Browse to choose where you want to save your file.
Select "CSV" from the "Save as type" drop-down menu.
Click Save
```